# Combobox's dropdown position for ipad (retina display) using As3 air application

Tags: actionscript-3, combobox, retina-display

the application which i created for ipad retina display in as3 mobile application. the combobox displayed in the screen in very small in size due to that changed the font, and size of the combo box dynamically.  which all almost work fine.  but the problem which was faced on the positioning of dropdown list, could not able to change the y position.

```
        var tf:TextFormat = new TextFormat();
        tf.font = "Arial";
        tf.size = 35;
        tf.color = 0x747070;

        var dp:DataProvider = new DataProvider();
        dp.addItem({label:"London", data:"item1"});
        dp.addItem({label:"Paris", data:"item2"});
        dp.addItem({label:"Sofia", data:"item3"});
        dp.addItem({label:"Praha", data:"item4"});
        dp.addItem({label:"Praha1", data:"item5"});
        dp.addItem({label:"Praha2", data:"item6"});

        _clip = new ComboBoxClip();
        _clip.combo.dataProvider = dp;
        _clip.combo.width = 199;
        _clip.combo.height = 50;
        _clip.combo.textField.setStyle("embedFonts", true);
        _clip.combo.textField.setStyle("textFormat", tf);
        _clip.combo.textField.setStyle("textPadding", 5);
        _clip.combo.dropdown.setStyle("cellRenderer", CustomCellRenderer);
        _clip.combo.dropdown.rowHeight = 31;
        _clip.combo.dropdown.setStyle("paddingTop", 150);
        _clip.combo.addEventListener(Event.CHANGE, onComboChange);
        _clip.combo.tabIndex = 1;
        _clip.x = _clip.y = 30;
        addChild(_clip);
```

And the CustomeCellRenderer Class

```
public class CustomCellRenderer extends CellRenderer {

    public function CustomCellRenderer() {
        super();

        var tf:TextFormat = new TextFormat();
        tf.font = "Arial";
        tf.size = 35;
        tf.color = 0x747070;

        setStyle("embedFonts", true);
        setStyle("textFormat", tf);         
    }
    override protected function drawLayout():void {
        super.drawLayout()
        textField.y += 2;
        textField.x += 4;
    }

}
```

[image]

Comment: Where's the code for the combobox? You have to set the format for the items in the dropdown selections

Answer (score 1):

Change the comboBox & dropdown height, width and text size to meet your needs.

```
var dp:DataProvider = new DataProvider();
dp.addItem({label:"London", data:"item1"});
dp.addItem({label:"Paris", data:"item2"});
dp.addItem({label:"Sofia", data:"item3"});
dp.addItem({label:"Praha", data:"item4"});
dp.addItem({label:"Praha1", data:"item5"});
dp.addItem({label:"Praha2", data:"item6"});

var tf:TextFormat;
tf = new TextFormat("Arial", 22, 0x747070);
comboBox.textField.height = 22;
comboBox.textField.setStyle("textFormat", tf);
comboBox.dropdown.setRendererStyle("textFormat", tf);
comboBox.dropdown.rowHeight = 32; //height of dropdown row
comboBox.dropdownWidth = 199; //combox and dropdown same width
comboBox.width = 199; //combox and dropdown same width
comboBox.height = 36;
comboBox.move(100, 100); //(x,y) use this to position comboBox
comboBox.prompt = "Select Something"; //if you need a prompt
comboBox.selectedItem = comboBox.getItemAt(-1); //show prompt
comboBox.dataProvider = dp;
comboBox.addEventListener(Event.CHANGE, onComboChange);
addChild(comboBox);
```